# In Asyptotic notation if g(n) < f(n) is it possible to have f(n)<=c*g(n)

Tags: asymptotics

I am studying asymptotic notation and I was thinking of a possibility where if g(n) < f(n) is it possible to have f(n)<=c*g(n). For example if -
f(n)=6n+5 and g(n)=4n+5, such that it possible to say (6n+5)<=2*(4n+5) where 2 is c. Are f(n) and g(n) here valid function in term of asymptotic notation.

Comment: Yes, in this case. The intuition here is that even if $g(n)<f(n)$ it is possible to have $f(n)=O(g(n))$. This is true here since asymptotically $f$ and $g$ are the same. It wouldn't be so if you had $g(n)=n$ and $f(n) = n^2$. We'd have $g(n)=O(f(n))$ but it wouldn't be the case that $f(n)=O(g(n))$.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what the problem is here. Use the definition of O.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on the type of relation you want to define between f and g.

In O and Ω you just have to find one c>0 and one N for which the corresponding inequality between f and g holds and the relation shall be established.

In o and ω you have to show that for every c>0 you can find some N such that the corresponding inequality shall hold for all n > N.

Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) can help you understand it better.